# Is there a way to convert an Eclipse, 1 library + 2 application projects into an Android Studio, 2 build variants

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

This is the usual 1 library/2 app projects reason - free/paid version of the same app in eclipse.

Is there a way to easily convert this setup into an gradle/Android Studio project that uses build variants?  Preferably that won't confuse git too much?  ADT's export obviously doesn't do that for you.

Or would it be just easier to build up the gradle project from scratch?  Are there any good samples out there for gradle/2 variants?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Eclipse Export tool to generate gradle files for you. then you can easily export it in Android Studio

[image]

Comment: That only exports them as a lib project and 2 java projects.